# "DROP USER" taking up to 30 seconds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We're having an issue where doing a `DROP USER` in a single database (SQL Server 2008 R2) takes a very long time. It seems to fluctuate, but takes anywhere from 15 to 30 seconds. There aren't any DDL triggers acting on user-related events.

To make matters stranger, this only happens in a single database on the server, on the other databases (larger, with identical DDL triggers), the `DROP USER` command is instantaneous.

Have anyone else encountered something similar, and if you did, were you able to track down the cause?

Comment: Have you had a look with profiler? Generally theres something locking on the user in the systable

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to imagine the use case where this matters. Why do you need this to be fast?

Comment: what syntax is this? DROP USER.. is USER a table?

Comment: @hkf: Looking at the profiler, it certainly looks like something is wrong. When executing the query, it seems to be aquiring and releasing a lot of locks. I have to work on my profiler-fu, but certainly looks like this is the cause.

Comment: @ConradFrix: We have a fairly frequently used button in an admin panel that does this, this is actually causing query timeouts.

Comment: @Baz1nga: It's the command to delete a database user.

Comment: @ConradFrix it matters because generally you don't want to lock on systables too long, as it will block most other non-io tasks

Comment: Might be something here http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/694498/drop-user-takes-too-long-time-3-seconds to put you on the right track?

Comment: @hkf ok fair enough, but I'm asking a different question. Why would an application need to drop a user on-demand? Wouldn't it make more sense to de-authorize the user and then drop the user off-hours?

Comment: @ConradFrix Database level security I assume. Revoking permissions will take more time than dropping an user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resurrect an ancient thread; my coworker figured it out. The problem was related to a running service broker. The following statement fixed the issue:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a DDL trigger on the DROP_USER event?

Comment: We didn't, the culprit was a running service broker. But thank you for your suggestion. :-)